# Google compute engine instance created with container executes multiple times instead of a single time

Tags: containers, google-compute-engine, gcloud

There has been an issue with Google compute instances created with containers running the startup script up to 10-20 times.

**Case 1**:
The container is built through Docker, then pushed to the online registry, and then an instance is created with that container. The startup script "Test.py" is instantiated through the container creation instead of being built into the Docker File directly. The following command is used to create an instance with a container and arguments:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container busybox-vm --container-image gcr.io/example-project-id/ttime2 --container-command python --container-arg="/Test.py" --container-arg="Args"
```

**Case 2**:
Including the startup script (Test.py) and corresponding arguments within the docker image itself, and then instantiating an instance also resulted in multiple runs of the script.

**Notes**:

1. The startup script is ran as a sub-process so the standard output can be easily sent to a remote server where it can be monitored for debugging purposes.
2. The startup script is executed multiple times before the first execution is finished (as the end of the script kills the instance successfully).
3. When running this docker build locally, it performs as expected with just one code execution.
4. I've experienced this multiple startup script execution on several different docker images
5. Only one instance is created.

A solution it seems would be to check for subprocesses as they spawn and kill any duplicates, I'm just not sure how I'd identify them.

**Edit:If you have some general tips on tackling problems with containers that have "crashlooping" I'd like to accept that as an answer.** I was personally able to add the following flag *--container-restart-policy="never"* to the above gcloud command to get a large variety of tests to work (not sure why), so I'm done with this issue for now.

Comment: When you say startup script, are you referring to test.py or the VM startup script?

Comment: I will make an edit to clarify, thanks. Startup script only refers to test.py, in Case 2 it's included in the Docker File.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of many reasons. A good way to diagnose would be to:

1. change to `--container-command "sleep 50000"` and create a vm.
2. ssh into the vm and run `sudo -i`
3. run `docker ps -a` until you see a container of yours appear.
4. get its container id and `docker exec -it <ID> bash`(change to `sh` if necessary). Your container should be sleeping. This will let you go into your container.
5. execute `Test.py` from within your container to see if there's an error.

This requires your image to have `sleep`.

Comment: An update - Following your instructions, I was able to run the startup script, with successful code execution, except having to enter y/n to standard input when asked to overwrite a file.

Comment: @TheHighlightHub overwrite a file? I don’t know enough about your code to help further. Hopefully this helped.

Comment: I just meant to emphasize the standard input part as it's not expected behavior (doesn't occur on a locally run docker instance), hence my code doesn't explicitly enter anything, yet multiple code completions are observed. 
I appreciate the information about accessing the instance via ssh, I'll read more into some tools that'll help debug this thing.